# Copiar directório num servidor ftp usando nodejs

Tags: node.js, sftp

Estou a desenvolver uma aplicação em nodejs onde necessito de aceder a um servidor ftp e enviar algumas pastas para lá. Antes de fazer o put dessas pastas, quero efetuar um backup das pastas no servidor. Como consigo copiar um diretorio dentro do servidor ftp? A ideia é passar a pasta 'servidor_ftp/pasta1' para 'servidor_ftp/backup/pasta1'

Necessito de fazer primeiro o download da pasta e depois enviar a mesma para o servidor?
Atualmente estou a usar o modulo ssh2-sftp-client.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que a solução mais simples seria utilizar os métodos [downloadDir()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client#org74a33a7) e [uploadDir()](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ssh2-sftp-client#org98dcbdd) do próprio ssh2-sftp-client para fazer o download da pasta e enviar para nova pasta, que pode estar em outro servidor.

Abaixo um exemplo se as duas pastas forem no mesmo servidor, caso sejam duas pastas de servidores diferentes terá que fazer duas conexões com *sftp.connect()*

```js
    const sftp = require('ssh-sftp-client');
    const config = {
       host: {
         host: host
         username: username
         password: password,
       }
       folder: folder          // pasta no servidor a ser baixada
       local: local            // pasta no projeto
       bkp: bkp                // pasta de backup
    }
    await sftp.connect(config.host);
    await sftp.downloadDir(config.folder, config.local);
    await sftp.uploadDir(config.local, config.bkp);
    await sftp.end();
```

Você pode também usar bibliotecas para comprimir o diretório, como [nesse exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23935283/transfer-entire-directory-using-ssh2-in-nodejs)

Usando o ssh2-sftp-client, fiz um projeto parecido ao seu, mas no meu caso recebia uma pasta com arquivos .xls de um servidor A para transformar em .csv e enviar para um servidor B.

[Link do projeto](https://github.com/renandmc/sftp-xls-csv)

Comment: Seja bem vindo ao SOpt. Procure adicionar os exemplos à resposta, deixando os links somente para informações adicionais.

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, acho que o exemplo resolveria o problema.